# Image not displayed in QML

Tags: c++, qml

I'm trying to display an image in a **QML** `Window`.

**main.qml:**

```
import QtQuick

Window {
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    Image{
        anchors.fill: parent
        source: ":/imageResource/snow.jpeg"
    }
}
```

**CmakeLists:**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16)

project(qml_image VERSION 0.1 LANGUAGES CXX)

set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

find_package(Qt6 6.2 COMPONENTS Quick REQUIRED)

qt_add_executable(appqml_image
    main.cpp
    images.qrc
)

qt_add_qml_module(appqml_image
    URI qml_image
    VERSION 1.0
    QML_FILES main.qml 
)

set_target_properties(appqml_image PROPERTIES
    MACOSX_BUNDLE_GUI_IDENTIFIER my.example.com
    MACOSX_BUNDLE_BUNDLE_VERSION ${PROJECT_VERSION}
    MACOSX_BUNDLE_SHORT_VERSION_STRING ${PROJECT_VERSION_MAJOR}.${PROJECT_VERSION_MINOR}
    MACOSX_BUNDLE TRUE
    WIN32_EXECUTABLE TRUE
)

target_link_libraries(appqml_image
    PRIVATE Qt6::Quick)

install(TARGETS appqml_image
    BUNDLE DESTINATION .
    LIBRARY DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR})
```

**main.cpp:**

```
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    const QUrl url(u"qrc:/qml_image/main.qml"_qs);
    QObject::connect(&engine, &QQmlApplicationEngine::objectCreated,
                     &app, [url](QObject *obj, const QUrl &objUrl) {
        if (!obj && url == objUrl)
            QCoreApplication::exit(-1);
    }, Qt::QueuedConnection);
    engine.load(url);

    return app.exec();
}
```

**ResourceFileDir:**

[image: Resource Dir]

When I run my program, the image does not get diplayed. Why is that?

If I change the source directory to `qrc:/imageResource/snow.jpeg`, I get this error

> qrc:/qml_image/main.qml:9:5: QML Image: Cannot open: qrc:/imageResource/snow.jpeg

Answer (score 0):

Based on your project tree, I can guess what your `qrc` file looks like:

```
<RCC>
    <qresource>
        <file>imageResource/snow.jpeg</file>
    </qresource>
</RCC>
```

This reproduces the same result you're showing.

Change your `source` to :

```
source: "qrc:/imageResource/snow.jpeg"
```

This does produce the error you got:

```
qrc:/qml_image/main.qml:9:5: QML Image: Cannot open: qrc:/imageResource/snow.jpeg
```

And to fix that, you just need to add this line to your `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
set(CMAKE_AUTORCC ON)
```

I reproduced your problem, and this solution fixed it.